# Differentiation under integration sign technique

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, problem-solving, mathematical-physics

What is Richard Feynman's 
'differentiation under integration sign' technique?

Please state the technique and give an example.

I am a Physics undergrad.

Comment: To be clear, I'm guessing you mean to ask when you can say $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{b} f(x,t) \,dt\right) =  \displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,t)) \,dt$, right?

Comment: A bit off-topic : The Feynman-rule was mentioned by Howard Wolowitz in the "Big Bang theory".

Comment: There are several examples in the "Related" column now.

Comment: I read about it in "Surely You Are Joking, Mr. Feynman!". But the rule wasn't given.

Comment: [This](https://mathsatbolton.wordpress.com/2017/08/30/differentiating-integrals/) seems relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you want to calculate $\int x\cdot e^x dx$

Now start with $$F(a)=\int e^{ax}dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}+C$$

Differntiating with respect to $a$ gives $$F'(a)=\int xe^{ax}dx=\frac{xe^{ax}\cdot a-e^{ax}}{a^2}$$ due to the quotient rule

For $a=1$, we get $$\int x\cdot e^xdx=xe^x-e^x$$